# CosmosDB - Mongodb IsUpsert not working for bulk updates

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have been using the MongoDB API with CosmosDB (Server v3.6) quite extensively the last few months via .NET Core and latest MongoDB.Driver Nuget package (2.11.0).

Bulk Inserts and inserts work fine, but unfortunately, I cannot get bulk operations to work with the `IsUpsert=true` mode.

> **Note:**
>
> - We use `Polly` to manage rate limiting. As part of this, we handle `MongoWriteException, MongoExecutionTimeoutException, MongoCommandException` and `MongoBulkWriteExceptions`.
> - This issue can be observed for both sharded/non-sharded collections.

Specifically, given a list of non-sharded input documents `List<T> documents`, the following works fine:

1. Bulk Insert:

   ```
   await Collection.BulkWriteAsync(documents.Select(s => new InsertOneModel<T>(s)),...)
   ```
2. Bulk Update:

   ```
   await Collection.BulkWriteAsync(documents.Select(s =>
     new ReplaceOneModel<T>(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", item.Id), item) { IsUpsert = false }),...)
   ```

Unfortunately, if some of the documents are new documents, we should be able to use the bulk update code above as is - but simply set the IsUpsert flag to true... but alas, this isn't working.

Specifically, *given 50 existing documents and 50 new documents*:

- If document has Id of type `ObjectId` as primary key, for the first new document it processes, CosmosDb will incorrectly insert it with `Id=ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")` - and at that point no further documents will be inserted/updated. In this scenario:

  - `BulkWriteResult` returned with `MatchedCount=65, ModifiedCount=65, ProcessedRequests=100, RequestCount=100, Upserts=1, IsAcknowledged=true, IsModifiedCountAvailable=true, InsertedCount=0`
  - **No exception thrown.**
  - Note - only 51 documents are in the database, so one can't rely on `BulkWriteResult`
- If document has Id of type `int` as primary key then cosmos db seems to

  - give up processing documents at some random point. This appears more of a rate-limiting type of scenario...**EXCEPT that no exception is thrown**.
  - For example, update all 50 documents but only inserted 8. In this case, `BulkWriteResult` returns with `MatchedCount=50, ModifiedCount=50, ProcessedRequests=100, RequestCount=100, Upserts=8, IsAcknowledged=true, IsModifiedCountAvailable=true, InsertedCount=0`.

What am I missing? The `ObjectId` scenario seems totally broken; the other scenario could be coded around but it doesn't seem correct that no exception raised here.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else plaqued by this issue - the workarounds were far from straightforward, but here's what I ended up doing.

- **Documents with primary key of `ObjectId`**: This scenario works consistently in in both `CosmosDB` and `MongoDB` as long as you either use 'InsertOneModel<>' or `ReplaceOneModel<>` based on the value of the identifier being `ObjectId.Empty` or not. However, you may still have to deal with below mentioned ***off by one error***.
- **Documents with primary key other than `ObjectId`**: Definitely a **bug in `CosmosDb`** as I couldn't reproduce this scenario in official `MongoDB` implementation. To fix this, I had to apply the following two workarounds:

  - Throw a custom exception and update my existing `Polly` policies to retry the unprocessed requests just like how I normally do with the other `MongoDB` rate limiting exceptions typically thrown by `CosmosDB`. Sample code:

  ```
  BulkWriteResult<T> bulkWriteResult = await Collection
   .BulkWriteAsync(
       remainingWork,
       new BulkWriteOptions { BypassDocumentValidation = true },
       token);

  var actuallyProcessed = bulkWriteResult.DeletedCount + bulkWriteResult.InsertedCount +
                       bulkWriteResult.ModifiedCount + bulkWriteResult.Upserts?.Count;
  if (actuallyProcessed < bulkWriteResult.ProcessedRequests.Count)
  {
      // Off by one error: OCCASIONALLY, the last one processed is not actually processed
      // No way to detect this, unfortunately - hence the adjustment by 1
      actuallyProcessed = actuallyProcessed > 1 ? actuallyProcessed - 1 : 0;
      var processed = bulkWriteResult.ProcessedRequests.Take((int)actuallyProcessed)
          .ToList().AsReadOnly();
      var unprocessed = bulkWriteResult.ProcessedRequests.Skip((int)actuallyProcessed)
          .ToList().AsReadOnly();
      throw new CosmosDbRateLimitingBugException<T>(unprocessed, processed, bulkWriteResult);
  }
  ```
- **Off by one Error handling**. Not sure if this is needed in pure `MongoDB` implementations, but just like above, you also have to sometimes adjust processed records by 1. **Note: This issue apply regardless of using 'IsUpsert=true'.** Below code is a slightly simplified as I use `Polly.Context` to keep track of exceptions and processed/unprocessed records (not shown). Here `remainingWork` is the `WriteModel<T>` requests that have to be issued to next `BulkWriteAsync<>` call.

```
if (exception is MongoBulkWriteException<T> mostRecentException)
{
    var unProcessedRequests =
        mostRecentException.UnprocessedRequests.ToList();
    if (mostRecentException.WriteErrors.Any())
    {
        //get processed requests (without success) that failed and add to remainingWork
        var requestWithError = new[]
            {
                mostRecentException.Result.ProcessedRequests[
                    mostRecentException.WriteErrors[0].Index]
            };
        unProcessedRequests = unProcessedRequests.Concat(requestWithError).ToList();
    }

    remainingWork = unProcessedRequests.ToList();
}
else if (exception is CosmosDbRateLimitingBugException<T> cosmosDbBug)
{
    remainingWork = cosmosDbBug.UnprocessedRequests;
}
```

Comment: FYI - in spite of above workarounds, isUpsert=true DOES NOT WORK in Azure for non-ObjectIds scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your question/answer, you saved me some time. Pretty frustrating....